# Can a Safari Extension react on the creation of a new tab?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I am currently writing my first extension for Safari 5. I can't find a reference on what events an extension can react.

I want my extension to react on these events:

- when a new tab is created.
- when a new browser window is created.
- when the URL inside a tab changes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Create an [Injected Script](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html) and add it as an End Script. Set the Access Level of [Extension Website Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html) in the builder to All. Your Injected End Script will be called for every page that loads in Safari, which covers all of the cases you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, as of version 5.1

From [the Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html):

> In Safari 5.1 and later, you can listen for and respond to the
> following window and tab events:
>
> Open—Safari sends an "open" event to a window or tab when it is first
> opened.
>
> ...
>
> Navigate—Safari sends a "navigate" event to a tab when the main frame of the new URL has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference: [The Windows and Tabs API](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1)

**Edit:** Hmm... it seems it only documents how to do some actions, not how to listen to events :-/